# В каком виде лучше получать дизайн для разработки Android приложения?

Tags: android, material-design

Допустим нужно написать приложение состоящее из одного экрана по `Material Design`. В каком виде лучше просить его макет у дизайнера? В `.psd` мне не нравится так как приходится самому конвертировать пиксели в `dp`. Примеры от Google выполнены в формате `.ai`, мне кажется это хороший вариант. Или же сразу просить `.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это заказ, лучше вcё в готовом виде. Иначе смысла не вижу. Между front-end-dev и дизайнерами должна существовать прямая нить,  ходят слухи, что она иногда такая тонкая, что её не видно)

По хорошему всё должно быть подготовлено для верстки.

1. Макет представить в любом виде .psd - отлично. В .png .jpg и тд, тоже отлично, больше зависит уже от оформления. Самое главное, чтоб было удобно просматривать, его именно Вам.
2. Сама разметка кончено в готовом виде, .xml.
3. Ну и без ai, не обойтись. Если вы будете использовать векторную графику, например иконки. Запросите уже готовые VectorDrawable в .xml.

Не забывайте, что Ваше приложения может использоваться для разных устройств с разным разрешением. Обязательно укажите это в заказе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А плохим решением будет делать самому xml по макету дизайнера полностью в ai например? Или это лишняя работа?

Comment: да это очень плохое решение делать всё в ai, хороший дизайнер с Вас возьмет копейку за такой объем. А из всего этого макета вы возьмете 1 - 2 картинки. Лучше точно уточнить, что вам предоставить в векторах, а что для формы и что для работы.

Comment: Картинки думаю достаточно просто порезанные по плотностям брать, векторные не обязательно